# Laravel WhereHas() / orWhereHas not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to fetch data from two tables Employee and Company via search by typing Company name not by company Id the tables are linked with one to many Relationship.they rest search functionality is working perfectly.any help would be highly appreciated.

**Code in EmployeeController is :**

```
  public function searchemp(){

   if($search = \Request::get('q')){

       $employees = Employee::with('company')->with('nationality')->where(function($query) use ($search){

            $query->Where('BadgeCode','LIKE',"%$search%")
            ->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($search) {
                where('Company', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');    })
            ->orWhere('tazker','LIKE',"%$search%")
            ->orWhere('lastname','LIKE',"%$search%")
            ->orWhere('firstname','LIKE',"%$search%")
            ->orWhere('serialnumber','LIKE',"%$search%")
             ->orWhere('BadgeType','LIKE',"%$search%");
        })->orderBy('BadgeCode','desc')->paginate(20);

    }        else{
       $employees = Employee::with('company')->with('nationality')->latest()->paginate(5);
                 }
     return $employees;

}
```

**HTML Code in Employee.vue is :**

```
<div style="margin-left:450px; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-10px;">
              <h3 class="card-title">
                <div class="card-tools">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 250px;">
                    <input
                      name="table_search"
                      class="form-control float-right"
                      placeholder="Search"
                      @keyup="searchit"
                      v-model="search"
                      type="search"
                      aria-label="Search"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="searchit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </h3>
            </div>
```

**Script Code in Employee.vue is :**

```
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
employees :{},
     search: "",
    },
        methods: {
            searchit: _.debounce(() => {
              Fire.$emit("searching");
            }, 300),
    },

    created() {
        Fire.$on("searching", () => {
          let query = this.search;
          axios
            .get("api/findemployee?q=" + query)
            .then(data => {
              this.employees = data.data;
            })

            .catch(() => {});
        });
    }
    }
```

**API Rout is :**

```
Route::get('findemployee','API\EmployeeController@search');
```

Comment: Try my answer and give your feedback. If anything wrong let me know.

Comment: make sure the record includes `$search` is exists.